# LaravelインストーラーとComposer経由のインストールとの違いは？

Tags: php, laravel

Laravelのマニュアルを見ると、インストール方法が２つあります。

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation#install-laravel

- Laravelインストーラーを経由したインストール
- Composerを経由したインストール

この２つの方法に何か違いはあるのでしょうか？
インストール方法が２つある理由や使い分けについて教えてください。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist` は次のようなことをしています。

1. Packagist から最新のパッケージ情報を取得（ここに結構時間かかる）
2. `laravel/laravel` の依存関係を解決し、必要なパッケージとバージョンを列挙
3. それらをダウンロード、展開
4. composer.json に書かれた仕上げを実行

`laravel new hoge` の場合はこうです。

1. 上の流れで言うところの1～3を行ったアーカイブをダウンロード、展開
2. composer.json に書かれた仕上げを実行

Laravel に必要なものしかダウンロードしませんし、依存関係の解決をする必要もありません。

よって、インストーラーを使ったほうがインストールが速いです。

※`laravel/installer` 自体のインストールは create-project 並みに時間がかかる可能性があります

### 参考

- [Laravel5のインストール方法とディレクトリ構成について - Qiita](http://qiita.com/morisuke/items/bedb27418a65f6924fb1)
- [installer/NewCommand.php at master · laravel/installer](https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php)
- [create-project - Command-line interface / Commands - Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project)

Comment: どちらも最終的なoutputは同じということですよね。私の環境には古いLaravelインストーラ（ver1.1）が入っていたので、package.jsonに書かれた仕上げ処理が実行されていなかったようです。それで、私はチョット混乱したのですが、ver1.2にupdateしたら、outputが同一の物になりました。githubのソースコードのリンクを紹介頂けたことで気付けました。今後はスピードの速い、Laravelインストーラを安心して使えます。

Comment: 失礼、package.jsonではなくて、composer.jsonですね。

Answer (score 5):

Laravelインストーラの場合は、常に最新のバージョンがインストールされます。
Composer経由の場合、バージョンの指定が可能で、古いバージョンをインストールすることも可能です。

> composer create-project laravel/laravel PROJECT_NAME **4.2** --prefer-dist